# Polybase and Predicate Pushdown on Azure Data Lake Analytis

Tags: sql-server, azure-synapse

recently the connectivity from Azure SQL DW to Azure Data Laka Analytics via Polybase was announced. 
https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/blog/sql-data-warehouse-now-supports-seamless-integration-with-azure-data-lake-store/

does anyone know whether this also supports predicate pushdown similar to starting MapReduce Jobs against HDFS/Hadoop Sources?

thanks,
-gerhard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently it does not support predicate push down.

Comment: thanks!
any ideas if this might be supported in the future?
(would make sense from my point of view)

also, the blog post only mentions Azure SQL DW, how about SQL 2016 on-prem - will support for ADLS also come there?

Comment: I would post the suggestion here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/307516-sql-data-warehouse/category/171048-polybase

Comment: just created the feedback item:
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/307516-sql-data-warehouse/suggestions/18107260-predicate-pushdown-for-adls-sources

how about ADLS for SQL 2016 on-prem?